# How to use one column to cover another column and adopt another column value when NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My system is Python3.6 with pandas 0.24

There are 2 column `cola` and `colb` in my dataframe `df`as below:

```
cola   colb
A         C
C        NaN
NaN       C
C         D
```

I want to use `colb` to cover `cola` if both has row value,adopt `cola` if `colb` has no  value.

The expected result as below:

```
cola   colb      colc
A         C       C
C        NaN      C
NaN       C       C
C         D       D
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like `fillna` with `pd.Series`

```
df.colb.fillna(df.cola)
Out[593]: 
0    C
1    C
2    C
3    D
Name: colb, dtype: object
#df['colc']=df.colb.fillna(df.cola)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`

```
df['colc']=np.where(df['colb'].isnull(), df['cola'], df['colb'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  cola  colb colc
0     A     C    C
1     C  None    C
2  None     C    C
3     C     D    D
```